# How to manage the display on printer

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, printing

I am using PrimeFaces 4.0,  I try to print a form  that contains tables, I used PrimeFaces  printer [link here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/printer.xhtml) and it works well with the printer.
But the problem is that the table is not displayed on paper as it is displayed on the screen (the array size, the size of the writing etc ...)
I wanted to know how to manage the display on the printer or if there is a tool to integrate with eclipse that makes that easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your own css styles for print media or modify the existing ones so that themes are also available for print media.

For example add this to your css:

```
@media print {

    .dataTableClassName {
        width: 650 px;
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

And here you can style your dataTable to make it look like you want it on paper. I don't know if there are any tools that can help you with that. Firefox has an option to display print styles, but i don't like it that much.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: thank u for responce ... bu t how to link that withe primefaces printer ??

Comment: The primefaces printer component will automatically use your defined print styles.